# sequelize.js belongsTo not null doesn't work

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I made some API system with Node.js

Also use sequelize.js(version 4) for communicate with MySQL.

In my model, I defined two model.

[model.js]

// User model

```
export const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false
    },
    profile_image: {
        type: Sequelize.BLOB
    },
    phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(14),
        allowNull: true,
        unique: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(5),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    is_admin: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
})

// Image model
export const Image = sequelize.define('image', {
    file: {
        type: Sequelize.BLOB
    },
    location: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
    },
    caption: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: true
})
```

And defined association for connect model to each other.

```
Image.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'creator', targetKey: 'username', onDelete: 'CASCADE', allowNull: false});
User.hasMany(Image, {foreignKey: 'creator', allowNull: false});
```

In above code, I defined `allowNull: false` to prevent null.

But when I desc image, it allow null.

```
mysql> desc image;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file       | blob         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| caption    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| creator    | varchar(30)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How can I set `not null` to `creator(FK)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

After I defined `creator` column to Image model,

```
creator: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
    allowNull: false,
}
```

It works fine.

But, Why specify `allowNull: false` in association is not work?

(In previous, I didn't define FK column to model, because association create column automatically)

Answer (score 0):

`allowNull` has to be nested in a `foreignKey` object on both models for this to work.

```
Image.belongsTo(User, {onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: {allowNull: false}});
User.hasMany(Image, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}});
```